# Is there any git bash with nice interface for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, bash, user-interface

Recently started git in bash, after understanding the basics of code mode, but found it feeling bogus using git with a command prompt-like interface of Windows.
[image: git bash as cmd in windows]

I'm wondering is there any easy way I can change the default interface to something *cool*! What I can most is to use the "Properties" menu and change the color or font settings, but found the settings is a bit temporary, *aargh*. :(

Is there any way? Any easy way?

I'm in Windows 7 - 64 bit (and in another, Windows XP SP2 - 32 bit).

Comment: I think you are looking for an alternative Console. Try Conemu https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/ https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Screenshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I can suggest [Console2](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx), it has multi tab support and you can embed cmd, as you can Powershell, Cygwin and of course Git Bash.

I mainly use it with Git Bash and it works like a charm. It can be easily resized, you can scroll in it using the mouse wheel, the look is highly customizable and you can make the window transparent, which allows you to read text "behind" it.

To add the Git Bash as a tab you just have to navigate to the tabs menu, add a new tab where you set the Shell to something like the following path:

```
"C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/bash.exe" --login -i
```

---

You can download the tool [from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/).

Hope you enjoy!

**EDIT** It seems like there is also a fork from Console2: [ConsoleZ](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1164928-consolez-better-windows-command-prompt-a-console2-fork/).
I have never used this forked version, so I can't speak for it; I just wanted to include it for completeness' sake.