# What is a good alternative for gitbash?

Tags: git, git-bash

Is there a good alternative for gitbash or the node cli for windows? 
It gets really old to type the same things everyday instead of the program just remembering the paths I go to everyday. I also dont like the fact that you cant copy or paste very easily with gitbash.
I know that some cli's have that function (on a mac) but is there a similar cli for windows?

Comment: TortoiseGit, GitGUI and many more..ask google

Comment: both are gui, i need a cli , but thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried powershell from GitHub for Windows?

Comment: [This question may be of interest for you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26093245/is-there-any-git-bash-with-nice-interface-for-windows/26093631#26093631)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can setup aliases. For example I type `c "some message`  as an alias for `git commit -m "some message`.
You can do the same thing for paths. 
Console2 is a nice console app that allows copy and paste and has various other features. By the way you can copy and paste with git bash, just right click on the top bar. It is not a great solution though.

Comment: You can "right click to paste" in if you go to GitBash properties and enable QuickEditMode